# react-native-router-flux tabbar not showing

Tags: react-native, redux, react-router

I'm having a trouble showing the tabbar in react-native-router-flux.

Im creating my scenes like this. I was able to show the first tab of the tabbar but can't make the tabbar to show at the bottom. Thanks for any help.

```
const scenes = Actions.create(
  <Scene key='root' tabs={true} unmountScenes
      component={connect(stateToProps)(Switch)}
      selector={props => props.isLoggedIn ? 'tabBar' : 'login'}>
    <Scene key='splash' component={Splash} title=''
      hideNavBar={false} />
    <Scene key='login' component={Login} title=''
      hideNavBar={true} />
    <Scene key='signup' component={Signup} title='Signup'
      hideNavBar={false} />
    <Scene key="tabBar" tabs icon={TabbarIcon} tabBarStyle={styles.tabBarStyle}>
      <Scene key='home' component={Home} title='Home' initial={true}
        icon={TabbarIcon} />
      <Scene key='diary' component={Diary} title='Diary'
        icon={TabbarIcon} />
      <Scene key='cabinet' component={Cabinet} title='Cabinet'
        icon={TabbarIcon} />
    </Scene>
  </Scene>
);
```

UPDATE: This has been closed, since I fix the issue. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove `tabs` property from any scene but `tabBar`. Also remove `icon` property from `tabBar` scene. Everything else seems fine.

This should work:

```
const scenes = Actions.create(
  <Scene key='root' unmountScenes
      component={connect(stateToProps)(Switch)}
      selector={props => props.isLoggedIn ? 'tabBar' : 'login'}>
    <Scene key='splash' component={Splash} title=''
      hideNavBar={false} />
    <Scene key='login' component={Login} title=''
      hideNavBar={true} />
    <Scene key='signup' component={Signup} title='Signup'
      hideNavBar={false} />
    <Scene key="tabBar" tabs tabBarStyle={styles.tabBarStyle}>
      <Scene key='home' component={Home} title='Home' initial={true}
        icon={TabbarIcon} />
      <Scene key='diary' component={Diary} title='Diary'
        icon={TabbarIcon} />
      <Scene key='cabinet' component={Cabinet} title='Cabinet'
        icon={TabbarIcon} />
    </Scene>
  </Scene>
);
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene for you answer, I tried following your code but I got an error, 'A scene for key 'tabBar' does not exist.'. I assume this is because we remove the 'tabs' property from the scene 'root'. I tried putting it back and it run fine but I still can't find the tabbar.

Comment: As I know, a scene with children should not have a `component` property. While your root scene does. Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: Thanks @EugeneZinin for the efforts. I found what is causing the problem and it is because I did not declare the class 'TabbarIcon' at the top of the 'scenes' declaration. I'm still kinda adjusting from compiled language to scripting language, so I forgot this basic thing. Thank you anyways.